# navigate different page without reload

Tags: html

I am a noob to web development and  I have a question on link of a website. I found on some website on clicking links in navigation the page does not reload and the content changes.

A good example would be this website itself. When you open this website i.e. [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) and click on any other link on navigation link the url just changes to [stackoverflow.com/questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) if clicked on Questions link. where as in my webpage it shows `index.html` at first and on clicking on About Us link in navigation it shows another URL as `aboutus.html`.

Is this related to dynamic webpage? Could someone please help? Also the stackoverflow.com shows no extension like `.html`. Please help me to understand this. Thank you and would be obliged with your answer.

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started and https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/tutorials/wa-ajax/ (ignore the Java servlet parts).

Comment: And: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ And: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Answer (score 1):

That is because of url routing, routing can be done from server side as well as on client side.You can also learn about SPA(Single page application).[Visit here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

Basically, in case of server side page rendering.The server matches target url with a certain set of url rules specified by the developer and sends back a particular file.

When routing is done on client side,the routing rules are defined on clientside javascript.You can also read about 'routing using angularjs' or 'routing using reactjs'.Almost all the javascipt framework support url routing these day.

Hope, this clears your doubt.

Thank you